# MyBatis:I am puzzled when deal with transactions,and my frameworks are SSM(SpringMVC,Spring,MyBatis)

Tags: java, database, mybatis

Exception in thread "Thread-93" org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

#### The error may involve defaultParameterMap

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: update user_info_star set uid=?          ,hero = ?           ,equipment=?           ,kingdom=?           ,captain=?           ,camp=?          where uid=?;

#### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

; SQL []; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:254)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:54)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.updateUserStar(Unknown Source)
    at com.qile.game.tf.service.UserInfoService.updateUserStar(UserInfoService.java:459)
    at com.qile.game.tf.service.UserInfoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4c2e17f3.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.qile.game.tf.service.UserInfoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3dc2ca3_2.updateUserStar()
    at com.qile.game.tf.manager.UserStarUpgradeManager.doCalcHeroStar(UserStarUpgradeManager.java:112)
    at com.qile.game.tf.manager.UserStarUpgradeManager.access$000(UserStarUpgradeManager.java:15)
    at com.qile.game.tf.manager.UserStarUpgradeManager$1.run(UserStarUpgradeManager.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and I donnot know how to deal with this problem, anyone can help me,please?

Comment: There's probably nothing specific we can tell you without more information what you're doing that causes these deadlocks. Have you looked at MySQL's logs to see what's happening? There's plenty of help for deadlocks in MySQL's documentation.

Comment: I will try to find more information~thank u!